# Moving back 2 directories not working?

Tags: php, html, css, directory

Hello I am trying to move back 2 directories.

For example i have a file in my root folder ie: **/root/FILE** that links this stylesheet successfully with the file location being **/root/blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/CSS-FILE.css"**

```
<link href="blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Now I want to link in the same stylesheet in a file located in a folder that is **/root/eliquid/includes/FILE** and in there and I am attempting to use

```
 <link href="../../blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I also attempted

```
<link href="../..blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

But not sure what im doing wrong! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an absolute link rather than a relative link? If your CSS file is at `http://www.example.com/blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css` then you can include it on any page of your website as

```
<link href="/blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: for now ill give you a thumbs up and hope u can help figure out issue.

Comment: Even though the files are in the same place, those two links you gave are considered two separate websites. The only way to include a CSS file from www.westcoastvapesupply.com on eliquid.westcoastvapesupply.com is to use: http://www.westcoastvapesupply.com/blog/wp-content/themes/dazzling/inc/css/font-awesome.min.css (you must include the full website URL if you want to link to a file on a different website)

Comment: replacing the link exactly like that?

Comment: If you check out the console in the browser you're using, you'll probably see an error that looks like this:

Font from origin 'http://westcoastvapesupply.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://eliquid.westcoastvapesupply.com' is therefore not allowed access.

So the issue is that the font files that font-awesome is including aren't being loaded because they're on a different site.

Comment: So you either need to enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing on www.westcoastvapesupply.com, or you can copy the font-awesome CSS and fonts into a folder on the eliquid.westcoastvapesupply.com website and use that copy for the subdomain.